# How to dynamically copy array from php to javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I'm writing code in PHP and HTML for the server side coding of a GPS tracking system. The PHP code will access the coordinates of the GPS from a database. I've found HTML code to display those coordinates on a map(as a Polyline). In the database, a new tuple will be added almost every minute, so we cannot specify how many elements are in the array, before hand.

How do I dynamically copy an array from php to javascript?

[this](http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/google_maps_overlays.asp) is the website with the code for drawing the polyline.

Comment: Did you give a try with javascript?

Comment: use jquery+ajax for transmitting variables and json_encode in php script to make variables appropriate for js

Answer (score 3):

> How do I dynamically copy an array from php to javascript?

You can’t “copy” it at all, because PHP and JavaScript are two completely different worlds.

What you can do is transfer it in *text* form – for example by encoding it as JSON in your PHP script, echo-ing it out as JS code (or request it from the server in a new HTTP request via JSONP/AJAX), and parse it back into a JavaScript object or array structure.

Answer (score 1):

Give something like this a try:

```
<?php
$arr = array('cat', 'dog', 'mouse');
?>

<body>
    <script>
        var jsArr = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>;
        console.log(jsArr);
    </script>
</body>
```

Should output

```
["cat", "dog", "mouse"]
```

in console